# Deploy Sidekiq Pro on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

This is a question to help others, I've actually solved it but couldn't easily find an answer:

I'm having issues with Sidekiq Pro, I can't find how to install Sidekiq Pro  from the private gem server (contrybsys) on heroku.

Heroku rejects my deploy saying:

```
remote :       Authentication is required for gems.contribsys.com.

remote:        Please supply credentials for this source. You can do this by running:

remote:        bundle config gems.contribsys.com username:password

remote:        Bundler Output: Authentication is required for gems.contribsys.com.

remote:        Please supply credentials for this source. You can do this by running:

remote:        bundle config gems.contribsys.com username:password
```

Which I did locally to install the gem. Everything works out fine locally, but can't deploy it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
heroku config:set BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM=username:password
```

Then deploy

Comment: You can specify a particular app if have several: 
`heroku config:set BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM=username:password -a APP_NAME`